# Is there any way to detect in Windows app to detect device, hardware keyboard on the phone?

Tags: android, angularjs, iphone, sql-server, visual-studio

we are trying to design application where users can use it on Desktop, Tablet and Phone. Would like to detect the device they are using, the resolution of screen, physical keyboard if available. Is there any way we can do in the code?

Comment: using which technology are you developping it? It is not clear.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio, SQL Server, AngularJS

Comment: you should have mention it in question and question tags

Comment: is that a web application? or what?

Comment: just updated the tags, its Web Application

Comment: so basically, you need to detect OS, and physical keyboard of the device using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes Vlad, thanks for your help

Comment: now you can search for ready solution, or ask more clear question. I unfortunately can't answer it because I'm an Android developer, and not good with JS.

Comment: Thank you for the info  Vlad